# Making a Sieve of Eratosthenes more efficient & printing values of a boolean array

Tags: java, arrays

For a class assignment I was asked to write code in Java for the sieve of Eratosthenes and my code is VERY inefficient. It doesn't take long to run but I'm fairly certain there's room for another loop besides listing out everything as I did..

Here's my code:

```
public class test
{

    public static boolean[] myArray()
    {
        boolean[] myArray = new boolean[100];
        for(int i = 1;i <100; i++)
        {
                if(i % 2 ==0)
                    {
                        myArray[i] = true;
                    }
                if(i % 3 ==0)
                    {
                        myArray[i]= true;
                    }
                if(i % 5 ==0)
                {
                    myArray[i]= true;
                }
            if(i % 7 ==0)
                {
                    myArray[i]= true;
                }
            if(i % 11 ==0)
                {
                    myArray[i]= true;
                }
        }
        myArray[2]=false;
        myArray[3]=false;
        myArray[5]=false;
        myArray[7]=false;
        myArray[11]=false;

        return myArray;
    }       
}
```

Basically what I did was set all elements that are NOT prime numbers to true..

So my main 2 questions are
1. Is there any way I could implement a loop to make the code shorter
2. How do I print off all elements of this array that are true (prime)

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the mathematical procedure of the Seive, or are you just trying to find primes? Because finding primes can be done way better than with the seive of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @Kon well the whole lab question is based on the Sive so i kind of need to do it this way!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. The sieve is a long topic anyway:

```
public class test
{

    public static boolean[] myArray(int MAX)
    {
        boolean[] myArray = new boolean[MAX+1];
        // myArray[i] == false iff i is prime
        for(int i = 2; i*i <= MAX; i++) // optimization: i*i to not check repeated divisors
        {
            if (!myArray[i]) // if i is prime
                for (int j=i+i; j <= MAX; j += i) // mark all its multiples as not prime
                    myArray[j] = true;
        }
        return myArray;
    }    

    public static void print(int[] myArray) { // print the array once computed
        for (int i=2; i< myArray.length; ++i)
            if (!myArray[i])
                System.out.println(i+" is prime");
    }   
}
```

P.S.: the code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is marking all of the multiples of 2, 3, 5, 7, and 11 to `true`, then setting those numbers themselves to `false`, but you're doing all of that 100 times.

What you need to do for the Sieve is the following:

Initially, all numbers are "prime so far", until marked composite.

1. Mark all numbers in the array as `true`, i.e. "prime so far".
2. In your `for` loop, if that number is still `true`, it's prime.  Mark all of its multiples, starting at twice that number, `false` for being composite.  You can use an inner loop for this.
3. Else if that number is `false`, then it's composite and its multiples are already marked composite as well.
4. Stop your `for` loop after iterating through the square root of `100`, `10`.  This optimization is possible because you're not going to find any more numbers to mark composite.  If a number here is composite and a multiple of a number greater than `10`, then there is also a factor less than `10` that already marked that number as composite.